# PostgreSQL select only last row from each recursion

Tags: postgresql, recursion, recursive-query

Let's have an employee hierarchy given with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
                        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
                        first_name varchar NOT NULL,
                        manager_id integer,
                        FOREIGN KEY(manager_id) REFERENCES employee(id)
                     );
INSERT INTO employee(first_name, manager_id)
              VALUES('Arden',          null),
                    ('Oliver',         null),
                    ('Luisa',          null),
                    ('Amelia',         null),
                    ('Olivia',         null),
                    ('Lily',              2),
                    ('Ava',               2),
                    ('Isabella',          2),
                    ('Charlie',           2),
                    ('Beatrice',          3),
                    ('Stephanie',         3),
                    ('Emily',             3),
                    ('Mila',              3),
                    ('Isla',              4),
                    ('Ashley',            4),
                    ('James',             7),
                    ('Jack',              7),
                    ('William',           8),
                    ('Harry',             8),
                    ('Robin',             8);
```

For an employee, for instance with id = 20, we can find the highest level manager using query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
   SELECT
      0 cnt, id, first_name, manager_id
   FROM
      employee
   WHERE
      id = 20
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      cnt+1, employee.id, employee.first_name, employee.manager_id
   FROM
      cte INNER JOIN employee ON cte.manager_id = employee.id
)SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cnt = (SELECT max(cnt) FROM cte);
```

But I need to obtain the entire list of employees --- `highest_level_manager` like the following:

```
employee  |  highest_level_manager
----------------------------------
Robin     |    Oliver
Harry     |    Oliver
William   |    Oliver
Jack      |    Oliver
James     |    Oliver
Ashley    |    Amelia
Isla      |    Amelia
Mila      |    Luisa
Emili     |    Luisa
Stephanie |    Luisa
Beatrice  |    Luisa
Charlie   |    Oliver
Isabella  |    Oliver
Ava       |    Oliver
Lily      |    Oliver
Olivia    |    null
Amelia    |    null
Luisa     |    null
Oliver    |    null
Arden     |    null
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walk the tree for all employees. Reduce recursion to `ids`, add names in the final query:

```
with recursive cte as
(
    select
        id, manager_id, 0 as level
    from
        employee
    union all
    select
        c.id, e.manager_id, level+ 1
    from cte c
    join employee e on c.manager_id = e.id and e.manager_id is not null
)
select
    e.first_name as employee, 
    m.first_name as highest_level_manager
from (
    select distinct on(id) *
    from cte
    order by id desc, level desc
    ) c
join employee e on c.id = e.id
left join employee m on c.manager_id = m.id
```

See live demo in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=023478b99e0fb6a30110a0c2d8c863d2)

Comment: It is really beautiful solution! Thanks a lot!